# Satisfiability of a congruence modulo the greatest prime dividing $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Let $n=2^km\ \ ,k\ge1$ be a positive integer with $m$ odd ($>1$ )and $r$ the greatest prime that divides $m$. Now, are there $\frac{r-1}{2}$  numbers $a_i$, less than $\frac{n}{2}$ and coprime to $n$ that $\textbf{do not}$ satify the congruence $$a_{i_1}\equiv a_{i_2}\pmod r$$

I think yes. The numbers $a_i$ are also coprime to $r$. The congruence implies that differences of $a_i$s are all multiples of $r$ less than $n$. There are $\lfloor\frac{n}{2r}\rfloor$ multiples of $r$ less than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$. Now, $a_{i_1}$ and $a_{i_2}$ are just partitions of the $\lfloor\frac{n}{2r}\rfloor$ multiples of $r$ into two coprime parts. Are there $\frac{r-1}{2}$ such partitions? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $\frac n2 \neq m$ unless $k=1$.

Comment: @lulu thanks! edited.

Comment: Are you also requiring that $k≥1$?  If $k=0$ then it's easy to create counterexamples.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity and to show your efforts.  Can you handle special cases?  What if $n=2p$ for an odd prime $p$?  Or $n=2p^m$?

Comment: @lulu yes. I do require that. Edited

Comment: I think you are writing these questions hastily.  Your prior question had trivial, small counterexamples, for instance.  Why not check this claim for, say, all $n<100$?  And/or verify it for special cases?

Comment: @lulu I checked for $n=24$ and  it is true. Thus, it would be easily true for $2^k\cdot3$. But, I doubt when the value of $m$ increases

Comment: Checking one value isn't very much evidence.